# Is the new COVID-19 Tax Relief for California residents applicable to everyone?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, covid-19

There's news out regarding a [60-day extension](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/about-ftb/newsroom/news-releases/2020-2-more-time-to-file-pay-for-california-taxpayers-affected-by-the-covid-19-pandemic.html) for California residents "affected by the COVID-19 virus", but the wording they use is so vague. Everyone was affected.

Do they mean directly contracted the virus? Or is this truly everyone in California can have an extra 60 days to file and pay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It applies to "California taxpayers affected by the COVID-19 pandemic". According to [this FAQ](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/about-ftb/newsroom/covid-19/help-with-covid-19.html), you do not need to have been directly impacted by COVID-19 to qualify. You qualify if you "experience any difficulty in filing or paying, as a result of COVID-19". Admittedly, this is still vague. I believe that it is on the honor system. Basically anyone in California who believes they experienced any difficulty with taxes can claim this 60-day extension.

Comment: Do you know if we qualify for Federal tax relief as well?

Comment: @Laith: According to IRS [Notice 2020-17](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/n-20-17.pdf), any tax due on April 15, 2020 (including tax owed on 2019 tax return, as well as first quarter 2020 estimated taxes) are now due on July 15, 2020, and no interest or penalty will be charged on those taxes for the period between April 15 and July 15.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate you taking the time to dig this up. I hope others see this and take advantage of this relief. Thanks again!

Comment: @Laith: by the way, California [has just](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/about-ftb/newsroom/news-releases/2020-3-state-postpones-tax-deadlines-until-july-15-due-to-the-covid-19-pandemic.html) extended the tax deadline to July 15 for all taxpayers (not just those affected by COVID-19).

Comment: Update: Federal tax filing deadline has also been postponed to July 15 ([announcement](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/tax-day-now-july-15-treasury-irs-extend-filing-deadline-and-federal-tax-payments-regardless-of-amount-owed) and [Notice 2020-18](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/n-20-18.pdf)).